# Is "Peacemakers" a mistaken reference to Peacekeepers?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In Chapter Five of *Catching Fire* we have the following statement from Effie Trinket:

> "So, I was just having a peek around because district ruins are going to be all the rage this year, when two Peacemakers showed up and ordered me back to our quarters. One of them actually poked me with her gun!" says Effie.

The title "Peacemakers" seems out of place. Throughout the series they are called "Peace**keepers**".

- Are there in fact other instances where the term "Peacemakers" is used, such that there is nothing wrong with Effie's comment?
- Is this a mistake by Effie, likely meant to highlight her personality and/or that of Capitol citizens in general, in that they can't be bothered to know the correct terms for the people who enforce hardships on the districts?
- Is this merely an authorial/editorial mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The term also appears on one other occasion, in the first novel in the series.

> “Thank you,” I say. The baker’s not a very talkative man in the best
> of times, and today he has no words at all. “I had some of your bread
> this morning. My friend Gale gave you a squirrel for it.” He nods, as
> if remembering the squirrel. “Not your best trade,” I say. He shrugs
> as if it couldn’t possibly matter.
>
> Then I can’t think of anything else, so **we sit in silence until a
> Peacemaker summons him.** He rises and coughs to clear his throat. “I’ll
> keep an eye on the little girl. Make sure she’s eating.”
>
> <sub><sup>[The Hunger Games](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2767052-the-hunger-games)</sup></sub>

Note that only four paragraphs earlier *the same set of government soldiers* are referred to as "Peacekeepers" so it's not in the least bit clear what, if any, difference there is between a 'Peacekeeper' and a 'Peacemaker'.

> “I love you. I love you both.” And they’re saying it back and then the Peacekeeper orders them out and the door closes. I bury my head in one of the velvet pillows as if this can block the whole thing out.

At the very least we can probably rule out that it's an editorial (or authorial) mistake since it occurs in novels written more than a year apart and edited by two different sets of publishers.

Comment: I think I'd take the opposite conclusion here: given the same soldiers are referred to both ways, and both in the narrator's voice, it seems very likely that it *was* just a mistake on the author's part, and the editor didn't spot it. Two instances of the same mistake in a three-novel series, doesn't seem unlikely.

Comment: @IMSoP Agreed: separate "Peacemakers" don't really fit into the worldbuilding here. It's a typo on the part of the author or editor, should just be "Peacekeepers". Good catch by the OP btw!

Comment: @IMSoP - Two different publishing teams missed it on two separate occasions and haven't fixed it in a decade?

Comment: @Valorum I don't know much about the publishing process, but is there much opportunity for editors to fix such problems after the book has gone to press? If it's a mistake in the original manuscript, rather than the typesetting, there wouldn't seem to be any reason for an editor to get involved in straight-forward reprints, so someone would have to go out of their way to get it corrected - and how many copies have you checked to see if they have?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "two different sets of publishers".

Comment: @IMSoP - I've checked the original ebook (2008) release and the most recent ebook omnibus (2011) as well as the 2017 Kindle release and the audiobook for Hunger Games #1 on Audible

Comment: Upvoted for the research and citation, but I’d agree with the other commenters regarding the likely conclusion. If there are precisely two instances over the course of four long novels (each with probably hundreds of mentions of peacekeepers) it’s hard to believe that it was deliberate.

Comment: I read that as an intentional derogatory term.  I've certainly seen "peacemaker" applied in a negative context towards UN Peacekeeping Forces IRL. "Peace" being a politically-defined construct, some people will necessarily view it more as "enforcing" peace rather than "keeping" it.

Comment: Or could Peacemaker an elite squad of Peacekeeper? Like a pre-select round before become Officers.

Comment: @someoneuseless - Maybe. But at this point we're indulging in fan-fiction. Maybe they're a non-elite squad that the Peacekeepers can boss around.

Comment: I don't think the author would toss in some subtle detail like that on purpose. More likely this is a typo or some spelling program issue. For those who want to make a conspiracy out of it, then notably the term peacemaker exists in the Bible, from the famous Sermon on the Mount: "Blessed are the peacemakers...". And it is definitely something very positive, out of a christian context.

Comment: @Amarth - A spelling mistake that occurs in two separate novels, written separately more than a year apart and copy-edited by different people? That seems unlikely.

Comment: Well, I'd rather argue/speculate that Collins very likely knew of this famous part of the Bible and named her military Peacekeepers on purpose, not to have them mixed up. We'd need a quote from the author or some official errata from the publisher. I can't find either.

Comment: @Valorum I don't think it's that unlikely.  These books were huge sellers, out for years now, immensely discussed here, at Reddit, on Quora, etc. and Google shows that almost no one has caught this.  There's this post, and one question on Reddit, and a note in someone's blog, and that's it.  If there really was another explanation than typographical error you'd think it would have come up by now.